# Detached entity passed to persist: JPA OneToMany relations

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to set up save entity with children together, but I can't find how it is works, I tried to do like in all tutorials but always had a error detached entity passed to persist
this is my entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CurriculumVitaes")
public class CurriculumVitae {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    private String title;

    private String summary;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "curriculumVitae", targetEntity = Education.class, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<Education> educations = new ArrayList<>();

    public CurriculumVitae(){}

    public CurriculumVitae(Long id, String title, String summary){
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    public void addEducation(Education education) {
        if(this.educations.contains(education)){
            return;
        }
        this.educations.add(education);
        education.setCurriculumVitae(this);
    }

    public void removeEducation(Education education){
        if(this.educations.contains(education)){
            return;
        }
        this.educations.remove(education);
        education.setCurriculumVitae(null);
    }

    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (object == this)
            return true;
        if ((object == null) || !(object instanceof CurriculumVitae))
            return false;

        final CurriculumVitae a = (CurriculumVitae)object;

        if (id != null && a.getId() != null) {
            return id.equals(a.getId());
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and child entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Educations")
public class Education {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    private String title;

    private String areaOfStudy;

    private String description;   

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "curriculumVitaeId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private CurriculumVitae curriculumVitae;

    public Education(){}

    public Education(String title, String areaOfStudy, String description){
        this.title =  title;
        this.areaOfStudy = areaOfStudy;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public CurriculumVitae getCurriculumVitae() {
        return curriculumVitae;
    }

    public void setCurriculumVitae(CurriculumVitae curriculumVitae) {
        //prevent endless loop
        if (sameAsFormer(curriculumVitae))
            return ;
        //set new owner
        CurriculumVitae oldOwner = this.curriculumVitae;
        this.curriculumVitae = curriculumVitae;
        //remove from the old owner
        if (oldOwner!=null)
            oldOwner.removeEducation(this);
        //set myself into new owner
        if (curriculumVitae!=null)
            curriculumVitae.addEducation(this);
    }
    private boolean sameAsFormer(CurriculumVitae newOwner) {
        return this.curriculumVitae==null? newOwner == null : this.curriculumVitae.equals(newOwner);
    }

    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (object == this)
            return true;
        if ((object == null) || !(object instanceof Education))
            return false;

        final Education a = (Education)object;

        if (id != null && a.getId() != null) {
            return id.equals(a.getId());
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

How can I set up save entities all together with one repository method save?
without cascade it will not save inner entities.

```
@PostMapping
public @ResponseBody CurriculumVitaeViewModel addCurriculumVitae(@RequestBody SaveCurriculumVitaeRequest model){
    CurriculumVitae newCv = new CurriculumVitae();

    curriculumVitaeModelMapper.Map(model, newCv);

    for (EducationViewModel ed:model.getEducations()
         ) {
        Education newEd = new Education();

        educationModelMapper.Map(ed, newEd);
        newCv.addEducation(newEd);
    }

    CurriculumVitae savedCv = curriculumVitaeRepository.save(newCv);
```

Comment: Can you show the code to save?

Comment: So what's your question ? You already answered yourself. You can't save children without cascade with single save.

Comment: @Moler yes, but when I choose cascade.ALL it throws a error detached entity passed to persist

Comment: @Moler I edited it

Comment: I suppose in RequestBody you send Education with existing ID? Then you can't save it. Bcs it's in detached state. You should use merge instead.